# Showing tags inside html page

Tags: html, tags

I want to display a tag, inside the text, so that users see it. (for example, for a tutorial)
How do i do that? Is there a very basic and easy way?

Comment: I'm not sure if I would mark the question as a duplicate of the linked question. The OP states a purpose "(for a tutorial)" that motivated me to give an answer which wuoldn't make sense for the other more general question. Just my opionion though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write out the actual character of "less then" you type `&lt;`
To write out the actual character of "greater then" you type `&gt;`

Example:
<html> = `&lt;html&gt;`

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll accept it as soon as i can (in 8 mins)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use syntaxhighlighter from http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ to achieve the following effect. Its perfect for code tutorials

[image]

The code in HTML

```
   <pre name="code" class="brush:xml">
    &lt;p:button outcome="productDetail" value="Bookmark" icon="ui-icon-star"&gt;
        &lt;f:param name="productId" value="10" /&gt;
    &lt;/p:button&gt;

    &lt;p:button outcome="productDetail" value="With Icon" icon="ui-icon-star"&gt;
        &lt;f:param name="productId" value="20" /&gt;
    &lt;/p:button&gt;

    &lt;p:button outcome="productDetail" icon="ui-icon-star" title="Icon Only"&gt;
        &lt;f:param name="productId" value="30" /&gt;
    &lt;/p:button&gt;

    &lt;p:button outcome="productDetail" value="Bookmark" icon="ui-icon-star" disabled="true"&gt;
        &lt;f:param name="productId" value="40" /&gt;
    &lt;/p:button&gt;
</pre>
```

Comment: Sorry, but i don't have an idea what is that thing, nor accepting it... I think that KeAn's answer is much better and easier, that's why i will accept his answer as soon as 12 mins pass (cooldown from idk what)

Comment: yeps, posted without the comments, by accident

Comment: I would add what the `&lt;` and `&gt;` mean in terms of overall HTML as they are escape characters and if a user doesn't know what those are, your code could look like gibberish.